# Resolving an ID to a derived type at runtime

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have 100 classes derived from Base. Each of these Derived classes has a unique identifier between [0,100), known at compile time.

I have a function that takes an ID and needs to return a newly allocated instance of the derived class with that ID.

```
Base* CreateDerived(uint32_t id) {
    return new Derived...();
}
```

It's evidently not a good solution to have a huge switch case for each ID. An example of the best solution I can come up with is provided below, but I feel like there is a way to do this without the overhead introduced by the vtable.

```
struct RegisteredClass {
    static RegisteredClass* ClassTable[MAX_DERIVED_CLASSES];
    static Base* CreateDerived(int ID) { return ClassTable[ID]->Create(); }

    RegisteredClass(int ID) { ClassTable[ID] = this; }
    virtual Base* Create() = 0;
};

template<typename T, int ID>
struct Register : RegisteredClass {
    Register() : RegisteredClass(ID) { }
    virtual Base* Create() { return new T; }
};

class Derived34 : Base {
    static Register<Derived34, 34> _register;
};
```

Am I being silly, or is there another approach to this that doesn't require so much space?

Comment: I think this an acceptable solution, except the hard-coding of the boundary/ID and the lack of range checking when accessing the class table.

Comment: Yes, I omitted the finer points for the sake of presentation. I do find this approach acceptable, but I'd like to know if another solution (potentially with MPL) exists.

Comment: You can derive a per-class unique identifier, e.g. using boost::uuid, instead of your hard-coded IDs and use a std::map or the like instead of an array. Note though, this will have an impact on the performance.

Comment: Are you sure the space overhead of the vtables is that much of a problem? Assuming 32bit OS (double it for 64bit), each vtable takes 4 bytes, ClassTable adds 4 bytes for each RegisteredClass, and if you create a pool of RegisteredClass's you don't need any more than 8 or 16 bytes (depending on alignment) for each. That brings us to 24 bytes max per type (both data segment and heap), which means less than 2.5 KB. For 64 bit OS it can get up to 5KB. Even on most embedded systems I know that's pretty reasonable.

Comment: It's not a problem. I do have memory restrictions, but they aren't severe. I'm mostly just curious about alternate approaches.

Comment: @AlexP. Thanks. I did manage to get rid of the vtable by using pointers to template functions, so the only remaining overhead is the IDs and populating the array at runtime. I'm wondering whether constexpr might help, though my compiler doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

> It's evidently not a good solution to have a huge switch case for each
>   ID.

That's actually the abstract factory pattern, and it's widely used just as you described it. I would stick to it, as it's familiar to most programmers.

Your variant seems overly-complicated and hard to maintain.

Comment: Unless it can be generated completely by templates, the switch would be so hard to maintain that I wouldn't even consider it. The most correct solution to what I'm doing is a scripting system instead of hard-coded objects, but that's not possible at this time.

Comment: @dauphic why is the switch hard to maintain?

Comment: All 100 types would have to be manually added to it. If I were to add more derived types, I would have to remember to add them to the switch, as well

Comment: It might be widely used, but I would not use it if I had 100 different cases like dauphic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a situation where the old crusty macro capability can simplify the task and eliminate some errors.

```
#define CASE(n) case n: return new Derived##n

Base* CreateDerived(uint32_t id)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        CASE(1);
        CASE(2);
        CASE(3);
        // ...
        default:
            throw std::logic_error("Unhandled Derived## case");
    }
}

#undef CASE
```